# Rename output files to lowercase in Visual Studio build events?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For my own sanity when trying to move my files to a Unix machine, I need to automatically rename every output file to lowercase.
I *currently* just rename each of them manually and Windows's compatibility-enforced case-insensitivity will do the job for me (keeping the casing when Visual Studio rewrites the files), but I'd have to do this for every single file, which is rather annoying to do as the solution grows in file count. (and a pain in the bottom if I dare forget a file name)

How would I do this automatically through the project's build events?

Comment: `const string str = "my string"; var strLower = str.ToLower();`

Comment: Since you're using Visual Studio, you must also have access to Powershell. Use PS to rename your files in a build script... please don't use build events.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Not these build events...? http://puu.sh/8KUqP.png And what's with that code snippet in the first comment?

Comment: no, not there. build events sorta stink and are not friendly to multiple developer teams.

Comment: Just change your project's properties *one time* to specify a lowercase name. Done. (And of course, there's no reason to transfer temporary object files to another machine, so those don't matter.)

Comment: @CodyGray Most of my current dependencies (and they're many) are not available to me as projects files. And I foresee many more such dependencies in the future.

Comment: Ah, dependencies. You tricked me when you said "output files". I guess Visual Studio does make copies of dependencies, though, if you ask it to. Makes more sense now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running build events is not a good way to go. You're way better off having a dedicated build script to do the work for you.

Since you're on windows, checkout the use of PowerShell to run your builds... there's lots of resources out there. (personally I use [PSAKE](https://github.com/psake/psake) - pronounced sa-kee, as in Japanese rice wine)

Now, on to the renaming. Here's a snippet of code you can use to rename all files in a directory to the lower case equivalent.

Rename-Files.ps1

```
$dir = "$HOME\Projects\MyProjectDir\FilesToRename"
dir $dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.ToLower()}
```

then from the console

```
> .\Rename-Files.ps1
```

*note: don't forget to [elevate powershell permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx)*

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first sentence? It is the first time I hear that. Also, I am alone in the development.

Comment: build events are tied to your .csproj file. They're also tied to your environment. If your environment changes, there's a good chance your build events will break. Build scripts promote re-usability and portability. If you're hooked on Build Events, you can trigger the powershell script from within the build event. Personally I prefer the console fo that sort of thing, but hey... what ever floats your tractor.

Comment: Heh. I think that using the build events would be more friendly for multiple developers because I can let Visual Studio provide data such as the project path or output path. I suppose psake could do that too or something equivalent. I really prefer the friendliness of Visual Studio for a solution such as this, so I will look into running PowerShell files from the build events.

Comment: here's how http://davidfrette.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/creating-powershell-pre-build-and-post-build-events-for-visual-studio-projects/

Comment: I found that (first result on Google) and I will attempt this tomorrow, because it is late now.